# How can I tell if user is dragging iosSlider left or right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fire an event if the user is dragging the slider to the left, and another event if the user drag the slider to the right side, how can I do this?

Comment: What slider? Do you have any code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are refering to the scrollbar which appears when you have a div with an `overflow:scroll;`
First, create a var to store the last slider value.

```
var prevSliderPos = null;
```

Bind an event to the slider

```
$(".slider").bind("scroll",Slide);  

function Slide()
{
    if($(".slider").scrollLeft() < prevSliderPos)
    {
        //Run code - user has scrolled left
    }
    prevSliderPos = $(".slider").scrollLeft();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I modified the plugin with some custom made functions that load images via xml and also made a couple of functions to go forward or bacwards depending the image, now my problem comes when I drag the slider to the left on the first load of it, it doesn't display the last 2 images (I have 6) but wheni it finish the slide of all images there is no problem...

Comment: What I'm looking for is to execute my loa_prev function if the user drag the slider left on first load, my load_next() function is working great though...